# working with PNGs in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, png, alpha

I have PNG and need to know if it has an alpha (or if the alpha is completely white)?
How can I accomplish this in vb.net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Drawing.Image.Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.flags.aspx):

```
    Dim HasAlpha As Boolean
    Using I = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("c:\test.png")
        HasAlpha = (I.Flags And System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFlags.HasAlpha) = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFlags.HasAlpha
    End Using
```